# FAL file title won't show in front-end with file collection "folder from Storage"

Tags: typo3, fluid, fal, fluid-styled-content, file-link

.

Hello
it's hard to explain ...

If you're using TYPO3 7.6 (w. `fluid styled content`) with the module "file links", you can upload single files, but you can also work with the "file collection" to organize your downloads in a sys-folder.

There're three different types of "file collections". 1. `Static selection of files` and 2. `Folder from Storrage` and 3. `Select by category`.

Now you've upload and edit your FAL-files (metadata, s. image below) with a new title and description. These fields e.g. `{file.title}` will show with `fluid_styled_content` (Uploads.html), if you're using a single download or a file collection `static selection of files`, but **not**, if you're using `Folder from storrage`! The title won't show, you only see the `{file.name}` ..?

I'm using the standard `Uploads.html`form FSC with an extra condition.
Test `<f:debug>{file.title}</f:debug>`, see below. There's no Title from files via "folder from storrage".

```
...
 <f:if condition="{file.title}">
    <f:then>
      {file.title} 
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
      {file.name} 
    </f:else>
</f:if>
...
```

Is it a bug or a feature for `TYPO3 8`?

I hope my pictures can explain this behavior better.

[image: select file collection]

[image: show file collection in front end with fluid styles content FSC]

[image: Insert Title (FAL)]

[image: f:debug file.title]

Comment: TYPO3 Forge, see: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [TYPO3 Core Bug](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78900), but now it's fixed (`TYPO3 7.6.15`) - update Core and `Fluid Styled Content`-Template **Uploads.html**

Line 26

```
<a href="{file.publicUrl}"{f:if(condition:data.target,then:' target="{data.target}"')}>
  <span class="ce-uploads-fileName">
    <f:if condition="{file.properties.title}">
    <f:then>
        {file.properties.title}
    </f:then>
    <f:else>
        {file.name}
    </f:else>
    </f:if>
  </span>
</a>
```

Thanks to the TYPO3 Core Development Team! [See revision](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/repository/revisions/e0ae7d82b1a0d8a206b4f7163251f434c870cd84).